# to infinitive analysis

Tags: grammar

1.I failed to persuade her.

Does the grammar see this to infinitive phrase as an object, if the 'fail' is a transitive verb, or as an adverbial, if the 'fail' is an intransitive verb?

2. The bomb is about to blow!

Does the grammar see the to infinitive as an object, or as an adverbial?

Comment: To infinitive and beyond!!  What more do you need to know??

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that, grammatically, the "to" infinitives are not adverbial and they are not objects. They are verbs -  [infinitives](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/) that are serving different purposes, through different mechanisms.

> 1. I failed to persuade her.

From my linked article above, the purpose of the infinitive "to pursuade" in this case is *to indicate the purpose or intention of an action*. The action is that [I] the subject [failed]. What goal or purpose did "I fail"? The purpose was [to persuade] the direct object, which is [her].

[I] is the agent and the subject.

[failed] is the main verb, in concord with the agent. It can be both transitive and intransitive aka it is ambitransitive. We could say "I failed" **and** we could say "I failed her" - both of those are grammatical.

[Her] is the 3rd person objective pronoun. Grammatically, it is the direct object.

---

**EDIT**

> 3. I want to go outside [from the comments]

I did some more research, and I found [this webpage about](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/want) the verb "want". I noticed something about "want" because of this site - "want" is an action. It's possible to both *want an object* (like in the sense of wanting to buy something), and to *want to take an action* (like wanting to walk). Grammatically, the information about *who* is doing an action will already be on the main verb. So if the action is to take another action, then the second action will be either in the "to" infinitive or the "zero infinitive". If there is a specific name for verbs that do this, though, it is outside my ability. This also might be relevant information for example (1), but I am reluctant to speculate much on it.

---

> 2. The bomb is about to blow!

**EDIT**

I realized that addressing this example as a main verb and an auxiliary verb is more accurate grammatically. Thus, I edited my answer. Here is a quote about auxiliary verbs from [Ginger Grammar](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/auxiliary-or-helping-verbs/):

> Auxiliary (or Helping) verbs are used together with a main verb to show the verb’s tense or to form a negative or question. The most common auxiliary verbs are have, be, and do.

[The bomb] is the subject.

[is] is the auxiliary verb (it is a conjugated form of the verb "to be," but is being used in a special way in this case), in concord with the subject.

[about] is [grammatically an adverb](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/about) here, indicating  *nearly or almost*.

[to blow] is the main verb.

The reasoning for this is that *the main verb* is the one which *is the action of the subject*. Since the bomb is the subject, the action **to blow**  - simply existing ("is" as the main verb), is not the action in this case.

If we wanted to see this in present tense, it would be **The bomb blows** = the bomb explodes right now. Adding the present-tense auxiliary verb "is" grammatically indicates *when* the bomb blows up. In this case, **The bomb is blowing** = the bomb is exploding in this moment, and will continue to.

Lastly, adding the adverb "about" gives even more information about the state of the bomb. **The bomb is about to blow** = the bomb explodes very soon, but has not started to yet.

Comment: I think your intention is the same as mine. I said 'advebial' because I thought  the two to infinitives decribe the verbs. The first one was to describe what the subject intended to fullfill, and the second one was to decribe the bomb's destine or future.

Comment: Then I have one more question to ask. "I want to go outside." Is this to infinitive an object? If not, is it an adverbial that decribes the subject's desire?

Comment: And thanks for your help.

Comment: I see! Perhaps this was a situation of lacking terminology then? Infinitives are verbs. It's just that infinitive verbs can be combined with other, conjugated verbs, to create more complicated meaning.

Comment: ....Also, I would not say the two "to" infinitives describe verbs. It would be more accurate to say that the "to" infinitives are used "in combination with" the other verbs. Or that the "to" infinitives are "working with" the other verbs. Using "describe" *sort of* makes sense, but the word's use is limited, because all verbs are actions, so an "action" [an infinitive verb] describing [a conjugated verb] looses meaning after a certain point.

Comment: Regarding "I want to go outside":  "I" is the 1st person singular pronoun, and is the subject and agent. "want" is the conjugated verb. "to go" is the infinitive verb. "outside" is a noun, and is the direct object.  So, "to go" is not an object -- our sentence already has one. "to go" is also not an adverb. In the meaning of the sentence, the speaker - the "I" - wants an action. That action is in the infinitive verb "to go".  "I want to go" is a grammatical sentence on its own. The direct object "outside" is added to state *where* the speaker wants to go.

Comment: And you are welcome! :D  Did this explanation on "I want to go outside" make sense? Would you like me to try to explain another way? @user375894

Comment: No, thanks. But thank you so much. Your answer was the best one I've ever received. I'll try to follow your analysis.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? Does our(your) way of seeing t.v.+to+v exists in the grammar? All I can find in textbooks, and on google is the analysis of seeing the to + v as an object.

Comment: @user375894 Of course! To the best of my knowledge, what I describe exists in grammar. Could you edit the body of your question to include links to the analysis you are looking at? I am uncertain how to answer further without looking at what you are reading. I think we might be conceptualizing (or thinking about) verbs in different ways, and trying to communicate this to each other is causing confusion. May I ask what your primary language is?

Comment: It's Korean. I'm from South Korea. I'm mainly reading Cambridge grammar in use series and Longman English grammar series. These don't give any analysis of the structure. They just call it 'to+v follows these verbs'.But I'm partly reading a Korean textbook. This one, like all Korean textbooks, sees the to-v as an object, but I doubt it. I think your analysis is right. I always thought so.

Comment: @user375894 Thank you for sharing! I have done a little more research, and I found something interesting about the verb "want" which might apply to two of your example sentences. it might help with the "to" infinitive issue. I think I understand better why "to-v" is considered an object by others. I appreciate that you favor my analysis!! I will have one more edit to do after this. I noticed that with "the bomb is about to blow" example, that "is" could be considered an auxiliary verb. I will edit my answer to clarify on that soon.

Comment: You're welcome! And thanks for everything!

Comment: You're welcome also!! I hope my last edits in the answer assist you well.

Comment: Hello again. I thought it was better to ask you directly than post a new question.

Comment: could you analyze these sentences?

Comment: I find it hard to get along with people./It's impossible to balance a paper bill on one's nose./He neglects to notify you of a change of address.

Comment: And one more, what is the role of 'to' in 't.v.+to+v'? And what is the connection between the two verbs? I want to hear your advanced knowledge

Comment: @user375894  I appreciate that you value my insight! Thank you for asking!! However, I am sorry to say that **it is better** to ask in a separate question, in this event. I say this because if *you* are asking about these sentences, then *other people* have asked, or will ask. Other people may benefit from learning about grammar in these. As long as we discuss these in comments, other users can't benefit because they cannot search them. Also, it would be useful to know what causes confusion in those sentences. Then we can discuss specific things to enhance your learning and your skills! :)

Comment: @user375894 An extra thought: these additional sentences are structured differently from the sentences we discussed earlier in this comment section and from the "question and answer" part. That is another reason to ask about these additional, longer sentences, in a separate question. The grammar in these longer sentences should be considered in a separate category from the sentences "I failed to persuade her" and "I want to go outside" and "The bomb is about to blow!"

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

Neither object nor adverbial but complement.

## Long Answer

There are many kinds of complements in a clause other than the object of a verb.

The *to*-infinitive construction itself such as *to persuade her* and *to blow* can be complement as well as adjunct (i.e., adverbial), depending on context.

In the given context of 1 and 2, however, it's not an adjunct. If the to-infinitive phrases were adjuncts in 1 and 2, you should be able to front them, but you can't:

> a. ?To persuade her, I failed.
>
> b. ?To blow, the bomb is about!

These are not objects either. In 1, the verb *fail* normally doesn't take an NP object denoting an action.

> a'. ?I failed the persuasion.

In 2, the preposition *about* cannot take a *to*-infinitive as object. Prepositions only take the V-ing form as object.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask two more question?   1. Is this to-infinitive an object?  'I want to drink some water./I wanna drink some water.'   2. Can the to-infinitve be used as objects?

Comment: No to-infinitive construction can be an object.

Comment: I want to know if Americans see this infinitive as an object('wanna know'), and if so, how?

Comment: Whether to use the form 'want to' or 'wanna' is not a syntactic matter but a orthographical matter.